# add nerdtree command

Tags: vim, nerdtree

i wanto add a command in nodetree.

for example if i press 'c' it has to execute 'o' command in NNERDTree and :AS command of alternateplugin in vim.

i tried to do some tries with nmap in vimrc but i didn't managed to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mapping should work to execute both commands:

```
nmap c o <Bar> :AS<CR>
```

`<Bar>` is used to separate multiple commands, allowing multiple commands on the same line. See `:help :\bar` for details.

I suggest that you avoid remapping `c` because `c{motion}` is a rather useful built-in vim command (see `:help c` for details).